# jquery to check a checkbox and act on the value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am using this jquery code in ASP.NET webforms to check the value of a checkbox and then turn a div on or off. It does not work...

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $('#checkboxOperator2').click(function () 
    {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
        {
            $('#showOperator2').show();
        } 
        else 
        {
            $('#showOperator2').hide();
        }

        alert("Click");
    });
});
```

I am referencing jquery like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager id="sm1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Is my code incorrect? I dont get any errors.

Here is my markup:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="checkboxOperator2" Checked='<%# Bind("SecondaryOperator") %>' runat="server" Style="position:absolute; top: 161px; left: 650px;" />

        <div id="showOperator2" style="visibility:hidden";>
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Secondary Operator" Style="position:absolute; top: 161px; left: 500px; width: 200px;"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownOperator2" runat="server" Style="position:absolute; top: 161px; left:650px; width: 200px;"
            Text='<%# Bind("SecondaryOperatorID") %>' AppendDataboundItems="true" DataSourceID="OperatorDS" DataTextField="OperatorName" DataValueField="ID" >
            <asp:ListItem text="None" Value="" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
```

Comment: As per my understanding your jquery code is correct. Can you confirm `jquery` is loaded

Comment: Karl Anderson I did not get the alert. @Satpal how can I confirm jquery loads?

Comment: @Ryan - put an alert in the first line below document ready function to test if jQuery is loading correctly. What browser are you using? jQuery 2.0 and later does not support IE8 or earlier. If you are targeting IE8 or earlier, then use jQuery 1.10.x instead of jQuery 2.x.

Comment: @KarlAnderson my jquery appears to be loading right. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess without seeing your markup, is that you need to get the `ClientID` of the ASP.NET check box control in your selector, like this:

```
$('#<%= checkboxOperator2.ClientID %>').click(function ()
```

When you have ASP.NET controls inside of naming containers (i.e. content placeholders in master pages), then it names the control at render-time by the hierarchy of the control, thus you end up with element names like this:

```
ctl00$body$checkboxOperator2
```

Since your jQuery selector is looking just for `checkboxOperator2`, then it does not match and the click event is not handled.

UPDATE:

If you do not like the `ClientID` approach, then you can apply a `class` attribute to your ASP.NET control, either through markup itself or in code-behind, like this:

Markup:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="checkboxOperator2" Checked='<%# Bind("SecondaryOperator") %>' 
              runat="server" class="checkboxOperator" 
              Style="position:absolute; top: 161px; left: 650px;" />
```

Code-behind:

```
this.checkboxOperator2.CssClass = "checkboxOperator";
```

Now your jQuery selector can be this simple:

```
$('.checkboxOperator').click(function ()
```

Comment: Would the element be named according to the item template it is in?

Comment: @Ryan - yes, the item template creates more layers of naming hierarchy. See updated answer.

Comment: That seems to be starting to get me on the right track. Why would I need to set the CssClass in the code behind? A checkbox element has a CssClass attribute as far as i can tell. However the div does not. I am assuming i need to id the div in a class the same way?

Comment: @Ryan - I was just putting the code-behind option if you are using server controls or HTML controls that have `runat="server"` in their markup.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to add an event to an ASP.Net control (or any DOM element, I guess) to add a `CssClass` to it.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="checkboxOperator2" CssClass="checkboxOperator2" Checked='<%# Bind("SecondaryOperator") %>' runat="server" Style="position:absolute; top: 161px; left: 650px;" />
```

Event handling

```
$('.checkboxOperator2').click(function ()
```